# DataTables warning: table id=tblList - Requested unknown parameter. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql-server

C#

```
[WebMethod]
public string loadLeaveRequests(int empID, int StatID, int isOwn)
{
    List<lstLeaveRequest> mylist = new List<lstLeaveRequest>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString()))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spLoadLeaveRequest", connection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = empID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Stat", SqlDbType.Int).Value = StatID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Own", SqlDbType.Int).Value = isOwn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            mylist.Add(new lstLeaveRequest
            {
                reqID = dr["reqID"].ToString(),
                dateFiled = dr["save_date"].ToString(),
                fname = dr["first_name"].ToString(),
                leaveType = dr["leaveAlias"].ToString(),
                dateFrom = dr["DateFrom"].ToString(),
                fromWhen = dr["FromWhen"].ToString(),
                dateTo = dr["DateTo"].ToString(),
                toWhen = dr["Towhen"].ToString(),
                reason = dr["Reason"].ToString(),
                remarks = dr["Remarks"].ToString(),
                sStatus = dr["sStatus"].ToString(),
                dateApprove = dr["approve_date"].ToString(),
                totalDays = dr["totalDays"].ToString(),
                grpID = dr["groupID"].ToString(),
            });
        }
        dr.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsn = jss.Serialize(mylist);
    return jsn;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function loadLeaveRequest(isOwn) {

    if ($('#tblList').hasClass('dataTable')) {
        $('#tblList').dataTable().fnDestroy();
        $('#tblList').removeClass('dataTable');
    }

    var xdata = "{'empID':'" + STATUS.USER_ID   //sa pgfifilter ng group kailang grpID lang ang makuha sa DB
                + "','StatID':'" + $('#cboStatus option:selected').val() //hindi na kailangan gumamit ng stored Procedure.
                + "','isOwn':'" + isOwn                                     //gumawa ng CommandType.Text sa bagong SELECT Clause
            + "'}";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../WebService/wsLeaveRequest.asmx/loadLeaveRequests',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: xdata,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#tbodyList').empty();
            var cells = eval("(" + response.d + ")");
            for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {

                var txtFromWhen;
                var txtToWhen;
                var disable = '';

                if (cells[i].fromWhen == 2) {
                    txtFromWhen = "(AM)";
                }
                else if (cells[i].fromWhen == 3) {
                    txtFromWhen = "(PM)";
                }
                else {
                    txtFromWhen = "";
                }

                if (cells[i].toWhen == 2) {
                    txtToWhen = "(AM)";
                }
                else if (cells[i].fromWhen == 3) {
                    txtToWhen = "(PM)";
                }
                else {
                    txtToWhen = "";
                }


                var sStat; //Convertion of int to String
                if (cells[i].sStatus == 1) {
                    sStat = "Approved";
                    disable = '';
                }
                else if (cells[i].sStatus == 2) {
                    sStat = "Denied";
                    disable = '';
                }
                else if (cells[i].sStatus == 3) {
                    sStat = "Cancelled";
                    disable = 'disabled'
                }
                else {
                    sStat = "Pending";
                    disable = '';
                }

                $('#tbodyList').append('<tr>'
                    + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" ' + disable + '></td>'
                    + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].reqID + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].fname + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].leaveType + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].dateFrom.substring(0, 10) + txtFromWhen + '~' + '<br>' + cells[i].dateTo.substring(0, 10) + txtToWhen + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].totalDays + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center; word-wrap: break-all;">' + cells[i].reason + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center; word-wrap: break-word;">' + cells[i].remarks + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="font-size:11px;">' + cells[i].dateFiled + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + sStat + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].dateApprove + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].grpID+ '</td>'

                + '</tr>');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#tblList').dataTable({

                "order": [],
                "destroy": true,
                "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets": 'no-sort',
                    "orderable": false,
                }]
            }).end();
            $('#tblList').css('width', '100%');
        }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<table id="tblList" class="table border bordered hovered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:10px; text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="cbAll"/></td>
            <td style="font-size:10px; text-align:center;">Request No.</td>
            <td style="font-size:10px; text-align:center;">Employee</td>                            
            <td style="font-size:10px; text-align:center;">Leave Type</td>
            <!--<td style="font-size:10px; text-align:center;" hidden>Group ID</td>-->
            <td style="font-size:10px; text-align:center;">Date of Leave</td>
            <td style="font-size:10px; text-align:center;">Total Days</td>
            <td style="font-size:10px; text-align:center;">Reason</td>
            <td style="font-size:10px; text-align:center;">Remarks</td>
            <td style="font-size:10px; text-align:center;">Date Filed</td>
            <td style="font-size:10px; text-align:center;">Status</td>
            <td style="font-size:10px; text-align:center;">Date Approved/Cancelled</td>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodyList">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spLoadLeaveRequest]
    @empID INT = 101, 
    @Stat INT = 99,
    @Own INT = 0
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SqlStr VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @SqlWhere VARCHAR(500)

    SET @SqlStr = 'select a.reqID, a.save_date, b.first_name, c.leaveAlias, d.groupID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a.DateFrom,101) DateFrom, a.FromWhen, 
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a.DateTo,101) DateTo, a.ToWhen, a.totalDays, a.Reason,a.Remarks, a.sStatus, 
                    a.approve_date, a.sStatusAdmin,a.approve_dateAdmin
                from tblLeaveRequest a 
                    join userinfo b on a.Save_User = b.empID
                    join tblLeaveType c on a.typeOfLeave=c.leaveID
                    join tblGroup d on b.groupNo = d.groupID
                WHERE YEAR(a.save_date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) '

    IF (SELECT userType FROM userinfo WHERE empID = @empID) = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @SqlWhere = ' AND b.empID = ' + CAST(@empID AS VARCHAR) + '' 
        END
    ELSE IF (SELECT userType FROM userinfo WHERE empID = @empID) = 2
        BEGIN
            IF  @Own = 1
                BEGIN
                    SET @SqlWhere = ' AND b.empID = ' + CAST(@empID AS VARCHAR) + '' 
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @SqlWhere = ' AND b.groupNo = ' + CAST((SELECT groupNo FROM userinfo WHERE empID = @empID) AS VARCHAR) + ' AND b.empID <> ' + CAST(@empID AS VARCHAR) + '' 
                END
        END
    ELSE IF (SELECT userType FROM userinfo WHERE empID = @empID) = 3
        BEGIN
            IF  @Own = 1
                BEGIN
                    SET @SqlWhere = ' AND b.empID = ' + CAST(@empID AS VARCHAR) + '' 
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @SqlWhere = ' AND b.empID <> ' + CAST(@empID AS VARCHAR) + '' 
                END
        END

    IF @Stat = 99
        BEGIN
            SET @SqlWhere = @SqlWhere
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @SqlWhere = @SqlWhere + ' AND a.sStatus=' + CAST(@Stat AS VARCHAR) + '' 
        END


    EXEC(@SqlStr + @SqlWhere + ' ORDER BY a.reqID DESC')

END
```

Can someone help me with this one. My code doesn't return all the values in the data table.

can someone find the bug in my code? it has an output but not all the database fields was returned, the Last item "grpID" is not shown in the table.

i know someone out there has a capability to solve this, so please help me guys Guys..

Comment: Your header column layout and column count does not match the data model returned from the server.

Comment: Yes, it does. I removed the commented column. now they are equal, but same status of output.

Comment: So _Yes, it does_ means 12 header columns (with uncomment) is equal to 13 data columns; got it. Anyway, what's the difference between `groupID` and `grpId`?

Comment: the groupID is a variable that will catch the value of grpID which is the database Field.

Comment: You are putting them both into your `tbodyList ` as columns. One as the first column and the other as the last column. But you only seem interested in defending you poorly constructed code than my help. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Sir. :) I already fix it :) thanks for the Time :D God Bless